# Azure function with Entity framework and OData filtering option

Tags: azure, function, entity-framework-core, odata, .net-6.0

Is it possible to implement in Azure function .net data retrieval from sql database using entity framework along with filtering using OData ?

```cs
private readonly TestScaffoldDbContext _dbContext;
public Function1(TestScaffoldDbContext dbContext)
{
    _dbContext = dbContext;
}

[FunctionName("TestReturn1")]
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<VmTest> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
    ILogger log)
{
    var features = req.ODataFeature();
    var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    builder.EntitySet<VmTest>("VmTest");
    IEdmModel model = builder.GetEdmModel();
    return _dbContext.VmTests;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes. It is possible to implement EF core and Odata filtering in Azure Functions.

Please refer to the below articles for the implementation of EF core

https://dev.to/azure/using-entity-framework-with-azure-functions-50aa

[https://markheath.net/post/ef-core-di-azure-functions#:~:text=Using%20Entity%20Framework%20Core%20on%20Azure%20Functions%20with,...%208%20Update%20Todo%20item%20...%20More%20items](https://markheath.net/post/ef-core-di-azure-functions#:%7E:text=Using%20Entity%20Framework%20Core%20on%20Azure%20Functions%20with,...%208%20Update%20Todo%20item%20...%20More%20items)

For odata implementation, you can use either of the following packages that are available in the VS marketplace

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Unchase.unchaseodataconnectedservice

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=marketplace.ODataConnectedService

Comment: Link-only answers have risk of link going dead. Please consider providing summary/steps from link to solve the problem.